# Eclipse won't open after update from Ninite.com

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I had Eclipse Juno installed on my Win 8 laptop. I then went to http://ninite.com/ and along with about 10 other applications, chose Eclipse and JDK. I ran the Ninite installer and after I came back my eclipse was closed. I've restarted my computer, but I cannot open my eclipse anymore. I don't know where Eclipse was located before, but searching my C drive, I see that an eclipse folder exists on the root of the C drive. I click it, and click eclipse.exe and nothing happens. Any ideas at all?

**Eclipse.ini**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

**java -version**

```
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

Running eclipse.exe from cmd doesn't produce any output.

```
C:\eclipse>eclipse.exe
HIT ENTER
C:\eclipse>
```

Comment: Try starting eclipse from a shell prompt, and post any errors that you see. Also post the contents of eclipse.ini. "Nothing happens" is vague, obtuse and doesn't help anyone trying to help you.

Comment: Well, "nothing happens" is the best I can do right now. Can you care to walk me through starting eclipse through a "shell" prompt.

Comment: Run `eclipse.exe` from your Windows command prompt (cmd.exe). Also, from looking at your eclipse.ini file, can you verify that right version of java is in your `%PATH%` ? You can do this by posting the output of `java -version`.

Comment: That's odd. Looks like a borked up install. I'm not sure you have a 64-bit Eclipse installation, but with a 64-bit JVM, you should be running the 64-bit Eclipse variant. You could probably dig further, by looking for [logfiles written by Eclipse into a workspace directory or elsewhere](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F) - this is unlikely if you dont have a workspace. Or better, you could just download and extract the 64-bit Eclipse distribution from eclipse.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a copy of Eclipse from the eclipse.org site and backup/delete the eclipse folder on your hard-drive. then extract the bundle you got from Eclipse.org in its place.

Comment: Yep, just needed replaced all the files from a new extracted copy of eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the eclipse log-files.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F